# Error when trying to install Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, error

I have a MacBook Air 11 (mid 2013), with OS X 10.8.5, and I want to install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), so I go to the [site](http://brew.sh/) and copy and paste the following code in my terminal:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

The thing is, I get the following error:

[image]

**Question:** What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*homebrew* requires additional installs before you can proceed: either Xcode or Xcode Command Line Tools.

You can download Xcode (2.1 GB) via App Store.app or the Command Line Tools at [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/downloads). Both require a valid Apple ID.

The latest CLT release is: Command Line Tools (OS X Mountain Lion) for Xcode April 2014 [direct link](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/command_line_tools_os_x_mountain_lion_for_xcode__april_2014/command_line_tools_for_osx_mountain_lion_april_2014.dmg) (~115 MB).

---

In later system versions you can open Terminal.app and enter `xcode-select --install` or just `gcc` to install the necessary tools. You will be asked to either *Get Xcode* or *Install*. Choosing Install will download and install the command line tools only.